# Android: Two animation together with different duration

Tags: android, animation, duration

I have two animation with different duration like below:
Anim 1:

```
    TranslateAnimation trans1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);  
    trans1.setStartOffset(0);  
    trans1.setDuration(5000);  
    trans1.setFillAfter(true);
```

Anim 2:

```
    TranslateAnimation trans2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -100, -200, -200);  
    trans2.setDuration(200);  
    trans2.setRepeatCount(25);  
    trans2.setFillAfter(true);
```

As you see these animation have different durations. I would like to animate Anim2 (duration 200) in loop 25 times during one time Anim1 (duration 5000) animation from Y: 0 to 500.

I've tried to do with AnimationSet and addAnimation but it doesn't want to work.
Could You give me some tips how can I solve this problem?

My code:

```
AnimationSet rootSet = new AnimationSet(true);   
rootSet.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());  
rootSet.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);  
rootSet.setRepeatCount(200);  
rootSet.setDuration(5000);  
rootSet.setFillAfter(true);  

    TranslateAnimation trans1 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, 500);  
    trans1.setStartOffset(0);  
    trans1.setDuration(5000);  
    trans1.setFillAfter(true);  

rootSet.addAnimation(trans1);


AnimationSet rootSet2 = new AnimationSet(true);  
rootSet2.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());  
rootSet2.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);  
rootSet2.setRepeatCount(200);  
rootSet2.setDuration(200);  

    TranslateAnimation trans2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -100, -200, -200);  
    trans2.setDuration(200);
    trans2.setRepeatCount(25);
    trans2.setFillAfter(true);

rootSet2.addAnimation(trans2);  

rootSet.addAnimation(rootSet2);  

iv.startAnimation(rootSet);
```

**EDIT:**
When I play only trans2 animation it repeats 25 times as I wanted (in horizontal way). 
And additionally I would like this animation to animate (whole horizontal animation not only imageview) in vertical way (trans1).

I hope that this description will be clearer.

When I added these two animations in one AnimationSet the first animation doesnt work at all and imageview (not animationn) is translated linear to -200,500.

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html#choreography

Comment: Thanks for answer but AnimatorSet is available since Android 3.0. I need something for 2.3+. I found NineOld library (http://nineoldandroids.com/) but I would like to know if is some simple solution of it.

Comment: Ok. Is it compulsory to use animationset then? Because I had done this using just 2 different animations (not parts of animation set), and it was playing simultaneously

Comment: It doesn't work is not very specific. Could you tell us *what* doesn't work?

Comment: One animation animates imageview in horizontal way and repeat 25 times the same animation, and I want to translate this WHOLE animation in vertical way. I want to have something LIKE what you do with finger when You reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I see what you want to do. You probably are better of doing multiple animations - one for each "line". Add an [`AnimationListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to know when the previous Animation ends (`onAnimationEnd` callback), jump down one line and go from right to left again.

They all basically are the same, just the `fromYDelta` and `toYDelta` values would change for each Animation.

Comment: Thanks. It can be solution for my problem :)